# Bash, search pattern in filename and compare it

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm trying to move file based on pattern via Bash Script.

I use find to select all my camcorder Files and stock result into TXT File.

Each of my camcorder file contain year location, I woule like to use Grep or something to find this string (year in 4 digits ie 1984) and compare this string to move file on different folder, if the file is after 1984 then my file must go in folder "Marie", if the file is before or egual to 1984 it must go to folder "Marie_Liam".

I've try several things, with Grep and while read -r line, but when I compare found string (year) my script return everytime after 1984 ...

Here are my different try :

I've try several things like this (it's a lot of try, not just one script) :

Base script :

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/CamFiles/ -name "*.m2ts"
```

Try 1 :

```
TestScriptResultFile="/home/Dio/CamCorderFindResult.file"
do
  if [ grep -e " 1984 " "$in" ];
  then
    echo "Voici un film qui est avant 1984 $FindMovie"
  else
    echo "Voici un film qui est de 1984 : $FindMovie"
  fi;
done
```

-- Another Try --

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ /bin/grep -E "[1][9][8][4]" "$MyLine" != 0 ]] ;
  then
    echo "Ok"
  fi
done < "$TestScriptResultFile"
while read line; do
  if  echo "$line" | grep -q "[1][9][8][4]"; then echo "$line"; fi
  Found=$(echo "$line" | grep -q "[1][9][0-8][0-4]")
  if [[ " $Found " <= 1984 ]]; then echo "$line"; fi
done < "$TestScriptResultFile"
exit 0
```

-- Another Try --

```
while read MyLine
do
  if grep -E "$MyPattern" "$MyLine"
  then
    echo "tourne apres 1984 : $MyLine"
  else
    echo "Tourne avant 1984 : $MyLine"
  fi
done < "$TestScriptResultFile"
```

Thanks for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: I've added my different try to my original post

Comment: I think all of your files contains string `1984`. To read exifinfo it's better to use `exiftool` or `exiftran`

Comment: This can be done without that information but it would be much simpler if you wrote a couple of lines of the names of your files to show where the year appears. If its place is constant, then the solution is short and obvious.

Comment: Year is'nt the only one string, On some file I have local postal code (where the movie was record), or range date expressing lenght of stay, and on some files I don't have any date ...
I can't use media tag, all my files was restored from a server RAID 6 crash (electric flash), and my files are for some corrupt and for all without any tags ... So I must use file name to order like it was before the crash ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the scripts based on the file name examples that you provided in your comment:

```
"Liam sur la moto (VHS) (2001) - Maison 13100.m2ts" 
"M&L Plage 1080i (2012) - Camargue 30240.m2ts
```

I came up with two methods to handle this naming convention.

The first is to assume that in every case the year is enclosed in parenthesis. I updated the 'first' script to reflect that case; it's simply an update to the regex pattern that is used.

```
regexPat='\(\K[0-9]{4,4}(?=\))'
```

The second script was updated to show a different method, where we can't be sure the year is surrounded by parenthesis. Here we read out the result from the grep evaluation as an array in case there are multiple matches, and then do a sanity check on the year - i.e the year must be between 1970 and 2020; otherwise we assume its not a year.

---

Note that the [`readarray`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) command (aka mapfile) is only in Bash versions 4.x+. At the bottom is a more portable version using just `read`. [It can be tricky](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) to parse the output of `find` without things breaking due to spaces or specials characters in the filenames.

#### Script 1

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create test files
touch abcd\({2001,1985,1984,1931}\)efgh.m2ts
touch abcd{24001,198a5,19b84,1912331,1293}.m2ts
touch "abcd 1232 adffd.m2ts"
touch "Liam sur la moto (VHS) (2001) - Maison 13100.m2ts"
touch "M&L Plage 1080i (2012) - Camargue 30240.m2ts" 
TestScriptResultFile="./CamCorderFindResult.file"
touch $TestScriptResultFile
   
regexPat='\(\K[0-9]{4,4}(?=\))'

readarray fileList <<<"$(IFS="\n" ; find . -name "*.m2ts" -exec basename {} \;)"
for i in "${fileList[@]}"; do 
  echo "Processing File: $i"
  if year=$(grep -oP "$regexPat" <<<"$i");    then
    if [ "$year" -le 1984 ]; then
      echo "1984 or earlier: $i" >> "$TestScriptResultFile"
    else
      echo "After 1984: $i" >> "$TestScriptResultFile"
    fi
  else
    echo "No valid year found in file $i"
  fi
done
```

1. Using the `find` command to get a file list and store it an array using `readarray`.

- Set the field seperator to a new line: `IFS=$'\n'`
- Use an `-exec` argument in `find` which will run `basename` on each file to get only the filename and not the path.
- The `find` output is directed into an array by using [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) and a '[Here String'](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings), `<<<` and the `readarray` command

2. Loop on the array of filenames

3. Use grep and regexPat to find the embedded year

- The regex pattern I used will match on 6 characters in a string when the first character is a `(`, followed by exactly 4 numbers `[0-9]{4,4}`, and closed out by a `)` at the end.
- In order to output only the 4 numbers in between (hopefully the year), the argument `-P` is given to grep for 'Perl Regex' which allows seperating matched characters from captured (output) characters, among other things.
- The `/K` will cause grep to not output anything that matches prior to the `/K` in the pattern (aka a [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).
- Finally, the closing `)` is removed from the output by using a look-behind non-capture similar to the `/K`. You can use the basically the same syntax for both, the bottom script shows the look-ahead method that doesn't use `/K`.
- the `-o` flag tells grep to only output the captured, matching portion of the string, which in our case will be a 4 digit number.

The rest of the script checks the number against 1984 and logs it accordingly.

---

Here's another more compact approach.

2 things to notice here

- `find` is given the argument `-print0` which will null terminate the
  output.
- The `read` command is given the argument `-d ''`, which tells it its input is null terminated. A null string is usually written`\0` in plain text; in Bash you can use `''` or `$'\0'`

#### Script 2

---

```
#!/bin/bash

TestScriptResultFile="./CamCorderFindResult.file"
touch $TestScriptResultFile

regexPat='(?<=[^0-9])[0-9]{4,4}(?=[^0-9])'
find . -name "*.m2ts" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' k; do
  i="$(basename "$k")"
   echo "Processing File: $i"
     if year=($(grep -oP "$regexPat" <<<"$i")); then
     for yr in "${year[@]}"; do
       if [ "$yr" -lt 1970 ] || [ "$yr" -gt 2020 ]; then
         echo "   x Out of range year ($yr) parsed from $i"
       else
         echo "   o Found year $yr"
         if [ "$yr" -le 1984 ]; then
           echo "1984 or earlier: $i" >> "$TestScriptResultFile"
         else
           echo "After 1984: $i" >> "$TestScriptResultFile"
         fi
      fi
     done
   else
     echo "   x No valid year found in file $i"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hello Agonauts,
A very big thanks for your script !
I've try each and no one is working as expected the first is blocked for each first digit, so if my file have 02-1980 or 720i for camcorder format process fail :
Dio@Dio:~#: ./StackOverFlow.sh: line 11: [: 1986
720: integer expression expected
Processing File: "Liam sur la moto (VHS) (2001) - Maison 13100.m2ts"
./StackOverFlow.sh: line 11: [: 2001
1080: integer expression expected
Processing File: "M&L Plage 1080i (2012) - Camargue 30240.m2ts"
./StackOverFlow.sh: line 11: [: 2012
1080: integer expression expected

Comment: I had to guess at the file naming method. Post some full examples of the names and I'll make sure it works with them.

Comment: Ok, thank you, You can see below a couple of my file name : 
Liam & Marie - Noel (1999) (DVR) Maison.avi
Liam 1985 - Etang (VHS) 84120.mp4
Marie - 1979 VHS Chez Francois.mp4
Marie - 1979 - Premiere Noel Maison (VHS).mp4
Liam - 1er match de Foot (1991) (720i).avi
Liam - Anniversaire avec les copains  (2006) (1080p).m2ts
Vacances en Famille 2004 - (1080p).m2ts
L&M Chez Tonton 12-02-1993 vhs.avi
Marie remise diplome (1999).avi
I have also some file who are in .mkv and .webm, they was self produced few years ago if they can be sorted as others are it would be nice! Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think the 2nd script should be effective for those files; for the other extensions you'll have to tweak the find statement.  If you get stuck post a response.

Comment: Script won't work :
   x No valid year found in file abcd1912331.m2ts
Processing File: abcd1293.m2ts
   x No valid year found in file abcd1293.m2ts
Processing File: abcd 1232 adffd.m2ts
   x No valid year found in file abcd 1232 adffd.m2ts
Processing File: Liam sur la moto (VHS) (2001) - Maison 13100.m2ts
   x No valid year found in file Liam sur la moto (VHS) (2001) - Maison 13100.m2ts
Processing File: M&L Plage 1080i (2012) - Camargue 30240.m2ts
   x No valid year found in file M&L Plage 1080i (2012) - Camargue 30240.m2ts

Comment: you'll have to modify the regex to accommodate the file naming conventions that you used. The two approaches I provided will work on 4 digit years surrounded by parentheses (1st one) and any 4 digit number with a non numeric character on either side. The latter method also filters out years that are too high or low to be real. The issue with pattern matching is that it is dependent on the naming pattern having been used to name the files - if that's inconsistent, things get increasingly more difficult to parse. Consider using multiple regex statements if the first check fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give a try to the pattern ! Thanks thanks !!!

Comment: Hello Argonauts, I've try a lot of things, and finally I've found the problem. Your script never neter in this part : 
if [ "$yr" -le 1984 ]; then
           echo "1984 or earlier: $i" >> "$TestScriptResultFile"
         else
           echo "After 1984: $i" >> "$TestScriptResultFile"
         fi
My pattern work, correct year is found, but when the pattern pass the first test (ie lighter than and greater than) instead of goin to the second test, the script stop like if the second test never been existing (ie if [ "$yr" -lt 1984 ]; then" can you point me the error please ?

Comment: I've miss to clic on save on my precedent comment .. Sorry

Comment: Script work only if year is out of range or not found, but never compared at 1984 ...

Comment: Ok I've found, all is working now !
Again a very big thanks !!!!

Comment: I have again a problem ...
All is working now, but your script remove full path for files, and as my files are ind ifferent folders, I can't move then, how keeping the orginal path ?

Comment: Inside the loop $k contains the full path and file name and $i contains just the filename, assuming you are using the 2nd script.  In the 1st script the full path isn't available.   But you could rework that easily

Comment: Ok thank you again, and again, thank you ! :)
Best regards,